# Getting error while trying to use Apex Debugger

Tags: debug

We recently purchased APEX debugger feature and when trying to use it from force.com IDE we are getting the following error.

> "Encountered an error executing remote command  Your Salesforce org
>   doesn't have the permission to debug Apex."

We have checked the permission for our Org and profile and it is enabled.

Any suggestions on how can we resolve this.

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like the feature is not active in the org you're using... I'd contact my SFDC AE

Comment: Hi Sebastain, I checked that with Salesforce support and the feature is active for my org.

Comment: Are you trying to debug production? That won't work. Make sure you're connected to your sandbox.

Comment: @sfdcfox Why debugging the production won't work ?

Comment: @cloudlover Because debugging causes code to stop on the server every time a breakpoint is reached. For every user in the system. As you might imagine, this could cause a bit of an inconvenience if you're working debugging an account trigger...

Comment: In addition the debugger affects performance on the entire pod and SF needs to maintain service levels.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox  - Yes, I was trying that in production org. I would get the feature enabled for one of the sandboxes and try again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have "Debug Apex" permission.
And have to contact Salesforce support team to get the permission to your organization.

For detail information please visit
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/debugger_set_up_parent.htm